# Confusion with determining Big-O notation?

Tags: c++, big-o

So, I really don't get Big O notation. I have been tasked with determining "O value" for this code segment.

```
for (int count =1; count < n; count++) // Runs n times, so linear, or O(N)
    { 
        int count2 = 1;        // Declares an integer, so constant, O(1)

        while (count2 < count) // Here's where I get confused. I recognize that it is a nested loop, but does that make it O(N^2)?
            {
                count2 = count2 * 2;   // I would expect this to be constant as well, O(N)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Think of O-notation as a "how fast do I get there" question. And it compounds multiplicatively for nested actions. Outer loop: `count` "gets there" in `n` complexity. Inner loop: `count2` "gets there" in `logN` complexity (you're doubling it with each iteration). This is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Ok WhozCraig, that makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WhosCraig - Just to clarify, Big O is *not* strictly about speed, or "how fast I get there." It can also describe the space complexity of a function, among other things.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher Absolutely. The term "fast" is not exactly a proper term, and I submit to that. Its about complexity, to be sure. I just think of that question in developing the difficulty of the problem being addressed, but you're quite right on the loose coupling.

Answer (score 2):

```
O(f(n))=g(n)
```

This implies that for some value `k`, `f(n)>g(n)` where `n>k`. This gives the upper bound for the function `g(n)`.

When you are asked to find `Big O` for some code,

1) Try to count the number of computations being performed in terms of `n` and thus getting `g(n)`.

2) Now try estimating the upper bound function of `g(n)`. That will be your answer.

Lets apply this procedure to your code.

Lets count the number of computations made. The statements `declaring` and `multiply by 2` take `O(1)` time. But these are executed repeatedly. We need to find how many times they are executed.

The outer loop executes for `n` times. Hence the first statement executes for `n` times. Now the number of times inner loop gets executed depends on value of `n`. For a given value of `n` it executes for `logn` times.

Now lets count the total number of computations performed,

```
log(1) + log(2) + log(3) +.... log(n) + n
```

Note that the last `n` is for the first statement. Simplifying the  above series we get:

```
= log(1*2*3*...n) + n

= log(n!) + n
```

We have

```
g(n)=log(n!) + n
```

Lets guess the upper bound for `log(n!)`.

Since,

```
1.2.3.4...n < n.n.n...(n times)
```

Hence,

```
log(n!) < log(n^n) for n>1
```

which implies

```
log(n!) = O(nlogn).
```

If you want a formal proof for this, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140961/why-is-logn-on-log-n) out. Since `nlogn` increases faster than `n` , we therefore have:

```
O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn)
```

Hence your final answer is `O(nlogn)`.